# How to create a read-only array in java?

Tags: arrays, clone

I want to get rid of clone() method.

For the below class sonar (static code check tool) was complaining that 
I *should not directly expose an internal array of the object* as one can change the array after the method call which in turn changes the object's state. It suggested to do a clone() of that array before returning so that object's state is not changed.

Below is my class...

```
class DevicePlatformAggregator implements IPlatformListings{
      private DevicePlatform[] platforms = null;

    public DevicePlatform[] getAllPlatforms() throws DevicePlatformNotFoundException {
        if (null != platforms) {
            return platforms.clone();
        }
            List<DevicePlatform> platformlist = new ArrayList<DevicePlatform>();
           ..... // code that populates platformlist
          platforms = platformlist.toArray(new DevicePlatform[platformlist.size()]);
        return platforms;
    }
    }
```

However I don't think its good to clone as its unnecessary to duplicate the data.

1. There is nothing similar to Collections.unmodifiableList() for array

   2. I can not change the return type of the method getAllPlatforms() to some

collection as it is an interface method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Java guru but I am pretty confident that you are out of luck here. There is no way to make a primitive array immutable apart from creating an array of `0` elements.

Making it `final` won't help cause only the reference pointing to it would be immutable.

As you already said the way to go in obtaining an unmodifiable *list* would be to use `Collections` as in the following example:

```
List<Integer> contentcannotbemodified= Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(13,1,8,6));
```

Hope it helps.